# Shifting a table header to the top of the page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to shift this entire table header to start at the top of my page however, after trying several times, I am still not able to do it.

[image: Current Picture of where my table is]

This is my code currently:

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="column" class="table" id ="table" border='1' align = "right" height="100">

<thead>

 <th bgcolor="#ed0924" text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;>Ranking</th>
 <th bgcolor="#ed0924">Name</th>
 <th bgcolor="#ed0924">Remaining HP</th>

[enter image description here][1]</thead>

<tbody id="mybody">

</tbody>
</table>
```

My code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6gogLnfp/

I guess the issue is that went I put it into jsfiddle, it appears on top of the page however, if you refer to my screenshot it goes all the way to the bottom. Only when I insert values it'll start shifting upwards.

Comment: I think there are some css styles (other than yours) which are being applied on your table. Can you check that once using debugger tools?
And, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Google Chrome

Comment: I still believe there are some other styles which are being applied on that table. If possible, can you share whole HTML code? Otherwise, use debugger tools to identify the CSS/style being applied on your `<table>`